# Reactivity of magnetized materials

Tags: reactivity, electronegativity, magnetism

- Does the magnetisation process affects the reactivity of a magnetic material?
- Does the electronegativity change if a metal is magnetised?

Comment: These are two entirely different realms.  With good precision, you may consider any influence nonexistent altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetization as a process condition (during synthesis procedure) can affect the crystal structure and nanoparticle size and morphology which in turn can affect accessibility of reactive sites. See the following papers:

Hu, Dawei, Yanmin Wang, and Qi Song. "Weakly magnetic field-assisted synthesis of magnetite nano-particles in oxidative co-precipitation." Particuology 7.5 (2009): 363-367.

Xiao, W., et al. "Magnetic-field-assisted synthesis of magnetite nanoparticles via thermal decomposition and their hyperthermia properties." CrystEngComm 17.19 (2015): 3652-3658.

Li, Yang, et al. "Fe 3 O 4@ PSC nanoparticle clusters with enhanced magnetic properties prepared by alternating-current magnetic field assisted co-precipitation." Colloids and Surfaces A: Physicochemical and Engineering Aspects 520 (2017): 348-354.

Comment: +1 for this. I was guessing that there must be some weird material reacted in some weird conditions that would show an effect. // Nanoparticles in general have weird behavior. Too big to be a "free" atom or molecule and too small to be the bulk material.